# jQuery click handlers which use data from attributes that are updated on success

Tags: jquery

I'm selecting a series of anchor elements and looping over them with $.each in order to assign each a click event handler.

On click I want to submit an ajax request which takes data from attributes on the anchor. The ajax request updates a boolean value on the server.

When that request is successful I want to update the data attributes of the anchor so that the next time it is clicked it sets the opposite value. I also want to add/remove a class to add a style to indicate that the switch is on or off.

What I've got so far will add the class and update the data attribute on the first click but won't do it on subsequent clicks:

```
<a href="#" class="ajax-link" data-value="0" data-method="car">Car</a>
<a href="#" class="ajax-link" data-value="0" data-method="bus">Bus</a>
<a href="#" class="ajax-link" data-value="0" data-method="train">Train</a>

$(".ajax-link").each(function(index) {
    $(this).on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var link = $(this);
        var method = link.data('method');
        var value = link.data('value');
        var data = 'method=' + method + '&value=' + value;

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'https://httpbin.org/get',
            data: data,
            success: function() {
                if (value == 0) {
                    link.attr('data-value', '1');
                    link.addClass('selected');
                } else if (value == 1) {
                    link.attr('data-value', '0');
                    link.removeClass('selected');
                }
            }
        })
    });
});
```

Codepen: [Editor view](https://codepen.io/paulyabsley/pen/LeBEOP?editors=1011), [Debug view](https://s.codepen.io/paulyabsley/debug/LeBEOP/wQAPoZybJgyr#)

Comment: `$(".ajax-link").click`...would be the same, no need for a loop. most jquery methods will be applied to all the elements matched by the selector. Click is one of those.

Comment: and don't swap round .data and .attr, use one or the other. There is a difference in behaviour (read the jquery .data() documentation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `.attr('data-value', value)` to `.data('value', value)` inside the success callback to make it work (plus you can omit the use of `$.each`):

```
$(".ajax-link").on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var link = $(this);
  var method = link.data('method');
  var value = link.data('value');
  var data = 'method=' + method + '&value=' + value;

  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'https://httpbin.org/get',
    data: data,
    success: function() {
      console.log(method, value);
      if (value == 0) {
        link.data('value', '1');
        link.addClass('selected');
      } else if (value == 1) {
        link.data('value', '0');
        link.removeClass('selected');
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZvjpKj?editors=1011

Comment: I ended up doing it the other way round, changing data('method') and data('value') to attr('data-method') and attr('data-value') instead but it has the same affect.

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
var method = link.attr('data-method');
var value = link.attr('data-value');
```

instead of

```
var method = link.data('method');
var value = link.data('value');
```